# Как в CSS сверстать неровную фигуру?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Нужно сверстать вот такую фигуру, но не знаю как правильно это сделать. Делал квадрат и через `before` добавлял обрезанный `border`, но на разных разрешениях экранов он как будто "отклеивался".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Повёрнутый градиент?

Comment: Gradient, SVG-объект или через before с поворотом и абсолютной позицией. Если нужно, прикрутим примеры.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, через бифор или градиент пример показать?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Первый вариант с градиентом:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;

  background: linear-gradient(105deg,  #000 0%, #000 25%, #ae0000 25%, #ae0000 100%);

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

И более объемный с `:before`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #ae0000;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-80deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-80deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-80deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-80deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-80deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

И вариант с SVG фоном:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;

  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NjAuMDAwMSAzNjQuNDU3Ij48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjE4Ni44MzYgMCAxNzkuMzMzIDAgMTMyLjE0MyAzNjQuNDU3IDY2MCAzNjQuNDU3IDY2MCAwIDE4Ni44MzYgMCIgZmlsbD0iI2FlMWExNyIvPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iMCAwIDAgMzY0LjQ1NyAxMzIuMTQzIDM2NC40NTcgMTc5LjMzMyAwIDAgMCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==') no-repeat center / cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Для работы последнего варианта во всех браузерах необходимо перегнать SVG код через любой [Base64 Encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/). Например, стиль такого вида:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 660.0001 364.457"><polygon points="186.836 0 179.333 0 132.143 364.457 660 364.457 660 0 186.836 0" fill="#ae1a17"/><polygon points="0 0 0 364.457 132.143 364.457 179.333 0 0 0"/></svg>') no-repeat center / cover;
```

Кодируем и заменяем, как в примере.

Comment: Вариант с svg почему-то не работает в FF.

Comment: Скорее, надо было правильно энкодинг сделать, чтоб побелы превратились в `%20` и остальные подозрительные сущности - тоже.

Comment: По правде говоря, было немного лень заменять скобки, пробелы и другие символы, поэтому просто заменил целиком в base64, тем более, что длинна получилась такой же.

Comment: В консоли браузера `encodeURIComponent`. Впрочем неожиданно, но в base64 получается короче. `s='PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NjAuMDAwMSAzNjQuNDU3Ij48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjE4Ni44MzYgMCAxNzkuMzMzIDAgMTMyLjE0MyAzNjQuNDU3IDY2MCAzNjQuNDU3IDY2MCAwIDE4Ni44MzYgMCIgZmlsbD0iI2FlMWExNyIvPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iMCAwIDAgMzY0LjQ1NyAxMzIuMTQzIDM2NC40NTcgMTc5LjMzMyAwIDAgMCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==';r=encodeURIComponent(atob(s));console.log(s.length,r.length);console.dir(r)` - 320 358.

Comment: `%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20660.0001%20364.457%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%22186.836%200%20179.333%200%20132.143%20364.457%20660%20364.457%20660%200%20186.836%200%22%20fill%3D%22%23ae1a17%22%2F%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%220%200%200%20364.457%20132.143%20364.457%20179.333%200%200%200%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E`

Comment: Да, тут нужно смотреть по ситуации. Обычно base64 длиннее, но, не в этом случае. Впрочем, я бы все равно использовал второй вариант решения.

Answer (score 13):

Если отвлечься от конкретного применения, где, по всей видимости, решение при помощи градиента является достаточным, такие фигуры можно верстать при помощи `clip-path`.

```css
.megablock {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  height: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.block--black {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #999);
  clip-path: url(#polygon-1);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.block--color {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 192, 255, 0.8), #ff9);
  clip-path: url(#polygon-2);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="megablock">
  <div class="block block--black"></div>
  <div class="block block--color"></div>
</div>

<svg class="clip">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="polygon-1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
      <polygon points="0 0, 0.8 0, 1 1, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
    
    <clipPath id="polygon-2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
      <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0.2 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но стоит отметить, что поддержка `clip-path` пока не очень впечатляет: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path.

Comment: Строго говоря, не работать совсем будет только в ИЕ, Эдже и Опере мини, можно считать это graceful degradation :)

Comment: Graceful degradation'ом это будет только если в одной из половин цвет фона не совпадёт с цветом шрифта ;)

Answer (score 8):

Решение через градиент:

```css
/* Чтобы не было скролла */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.with-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #000 30%, #ac0000 0);
  
  /* Просто для демонстрации */
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-gradient">
</div>
```

#### Небольшая заметка:

Я использую `0` как ступенях градиентов, чтобы не дублировать предыдущие значения, так как по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) ступенька градиента не может быть меньше предыдущего значения.

> If a color-stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color-stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color-stop before it.