# Градиентная заливка треугольника в CSS

Tags: html, css

Эта косая граница между двумя цветами сверстана как псевдоэлемент в виде прямого (прямоугольного) треугольника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать ему градиентную заливку, как на левом блоке? Спасибо!

Comment: так? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615186/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-css-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83/615327#615327

Comment: На каком левом блоке?

Comment: @sasha-omelchenko хороший способ, только градиент повернутый получается

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NDJ3S/15/

Comment: в общем, совсем не адаптивный элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте) Вы можете использовать ниже указанный background для градиента в верхнем левом углу:

`background:-webkit-gradient(radial, -36 22, 0, -47 -341, 465, from(#506B00), to(#DF4E28))`
или
`background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 27% 56%, 0% 0%, from(#0040BC), to(#C54928))`

Если Вам необходимо по всей левой части треугольника, то ниже указанный background:

`background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 26%, 0% 1%, from(#0040BC), to(#C54928))`

Цвета укажите необходимые Вам)