# Как сделать пару кривых блоков CSS?

Tags: html, css

Появилась следующая проблема: требуется сделать такую конструкцию ( рисунок приложен ), а я не могу понять, как это можно сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Возможно, не совсем правильно изложил суть вопроса. На рисунке показан не градиент, а два разных блока, между которыми имеется расстояние

Comment: Возможно дубликат [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015781/creating-a-diagonal-line-section-border-with-css), чекни это, вроде, решение твоей проблемы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в CSS сверстать неровную фигуру?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-css-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83)

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью `linear-gradient`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(65deg, blue 35%, white 0, white 50%, grey 0);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант решения с использованием [skewX](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

```css
.skew {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #F48024;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg); 
  -moz-transform: skewX(15deg); 
  -ms-transform: skewX(15deg); 
  -o-transform: skewX(15deg); 
  transform: skewX(15deg); 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="skew"></div>
</div>
```