# Как лучше организовать такой лендинг с косыми блоками?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет, я - начинающий и нужен совет по организации лендинга.

По вертикали чередуются трапецеидальные блоки (малое основание справа, большое - слева, следующий блок - наоборот и т.д.). Чередуются так же цвета блока (2 текстуры, т.е. НЕ сплошной однородный фон, а какая-то бэк-пикча). Следовательно, будет чередоваться 2 вида трапеций.
Планирую 1 бэк сделать общим фоном на родительский блок (родительский всех трапеций), а вторая текстура будет в полноценных трапецеидальных блоках, ну т.е. одна из трапеций будет формироваться как пространство между двумя трапециями другого цвета.
Во всех блоках будет контент.

Быть может схему компоновки лучше бы изменить. Что скажете ? Это всё пока что предварительно.

И ГЛАВНОЕ: перебираю способы создания вот этих вот скосов (напоминаю, бэк - изображение, текстура, а НЕ сплошной монотонный цвет). Заказчик требует поддержку IE9+, Safari, Opera ... Т.е. нужно использовать дедовские методы.

Что можете подсказать по скосам и вообще по теме?

Comment: хорошо бы картинку/эскиз посмотреть, а так "чередуются трапецеидальные блоки", "бэк", "бэк пикча" ... Можно достигнуть любого эффекта используя наложения фона. Для IE можно и нужно сделать более простой вариант.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в CSS сверстать неровную фигуру?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-css-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83)